# how to make text-overflow ellipsis 3 dots clickable?

Tags: css, vue.js

I wanted to ask is it possible that the CSS property **text-overflow: ellipsis** which has 3 dots can be made clickable.

Actually, I am using vuejs as the frontend and I have a scenario where the text is longer but I don't want the text to break instead it should be in one line and that problem is solved with this CSS property now I want if this 3 dots is held for a second then it should show the rest of the text.

OR if we click these 3 dots the rest of the words will be shown.

Can it be done in vuejs ??

Any help with an example would be appreciated

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you cannot do that but you could achieve that by using vuejs logic

Comment: any example you can give ?? on how to achieve it ?

Comment: please provide a running example as below and I will suggest an example based on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you need this

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      showLess: true
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.text-overflow-handle {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<div ref="text" @click="showLess = !showLess" :class="{'text-overflow-handle': showLess}">What is Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book it has?</div>
</div>
```

Comment: hey @MohammadAbedi thanks for the answer but the  issue is i already have a click event on that tag is there any idea if i hold that dot then only it will show